# Show attachment pane by default

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using latest version of **TCPDF** inorder to generate my PDF files and it is working fine

the problem where I stuck is **I want to display file attachment annotation pane by default** as it opens when user clicks on attachment image ...

I have tried the following :

```
$pdf->SetDisplayMode($zoom, $layout, $mode='UseAttachments');
```

but its not working.

Tell me how it is possible please ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my version of TCPDF, `SetDisplayMode` function looks like this:

```
public function SetDisplayMode($zoom, $layout='SinglePage', $mode='UseNone') {
        if (($zoom == 'fullpage') OR ($zoom == 'fullwidth') OR ($zoom == 'real') OR ($zoom == 'default') OR (!is_string($zoom))) {
            $this->ZoomMode = $zoom;
        } else {
            $this->Error('Incorrect zoom display mode: '.$zoom);
        }
        switch ($layout) {
            //layout is set here
        }
        //page mode
        switch ($mode) {
            case 'UseNone': {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseNone';
                break;
            }
            case 'UseOutlines': {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseOutlines';
                break;
            }
            case 'UseThumbs': {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseThumbs';
                break;
            }
            case 'FullScreen': {
                $this->PageMode = 'FullScreen';
                break;
            }
            case 'UseOC': {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseOC';
                break;
            }
            case '': {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseAttachments';
                break;
            }
            default: {
                $this->PageMode = 'UseNone';
            }
        }
    }
```

Take a look at the last case. It will set a PageMode to "UseAttachments", but it looks to be defined in wrong way. Instead of `case 'UseAttachments':` there is `case '':`.

So, try to change your code to this:

```
$pdf->SetDisplayMode($zoom, $layout, '');
```